# Github Commit into remote changes, and not get last changes from remote master

Tags: git, github

Imagine situation.

1. I create new branch from master (b1) and change file test.txt.
2. I create new branch from master (b2) and also change file test.txt
3. I push branch b2 to remote master. OK.
4. I tried push branch b1 to remote master, but I cant't, file is changed.

I need merge b1 with remote master without git fetch origin, because I don't need get last changes into my local branch.

```
           b1 ---(changed test.txt)--

master ---/--------------------------\--------

           \b2-(changed test.txt)-----------/(conflict)
```

Why I need that..
If I do realize, I can chose what branches I add into realize.
For example I want only b2 without b1.
Why I merge with master branches? It for code review.

If I can't in remote merge automatically branch with master, I want to show problem files and maybe change it manually.

Comment: `git checkout master; git merge b1 b2; git push origin`

Comment: Thanks for answer. But if i don't know where is the conflict? Github web show only than 'Github can not merge automaticaly', but not show files.
And if before me, was commited 20 branches. I never now in with files was conflict.

Comment: And if i merge  b1 with b2, after if i want realise only b1 branch, i can't do that, because with branch b1 i get b2 changes...